# Read/Add ID3 Tags from .mp3s to HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, web, mp3, id3

After doing some research, I found this link to a "guide" on PHP: [ID3 Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.id3.php). I'm not quite sure how to go about implementing this into a website so that:

- Finds all .mp3's in a folder
- Reads the ID3 tags from the file (Artist, year, etc.)
- Allows me to put the ID3 tags along with a link to the file on an
  HTML website

I already have the finding all .mp3's in a folder working, but I'm not sure how to implement the ID3 functions to read from those files.

Comment: run `id3_get_tag();` on each file one at a time. glog(), foreach(), id3_get_tag(). Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID3 package is long abandoned and no longer shipped with **PHP 7 and up**.
Check out [getID3](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3) for an alternative.

---

**PHP 5:**

Easiest way would probably be [`id3_get_tag($filename, $version)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.id3-get-tag.php).

Just provide a string containing the file path and optionally a ID3 Tag version (leave out if you don't know):

```
$files = array('/folder/file1.mp3', '/folder/file2.mp3');
$tags = array();
foreach($files as $file) {
    $tags[$file] = id3_get_tag($file);
    // convert genre:
    if(array_key_exists('genre', $tags[$file]) && is_integer($tags[$file]['genre'])
       && $tags[$file]['genre'] >= 0 && $tags[$file]['genre'] <= 147) {
        $tags[$file]['genre'] = id3_get_genre_name($tags[$file]['genre']);
    }
}
```

`$tags` will then be an array like this:

```
['/folder/file1.mp3'] = array('interpret' => 'John Doe', 'title' => 'PHP is cool', 'genre' => 'Techno')
['/folder/file2.mp3'] = array('interpret' => 'Jane Doe', 'title' => 'ASP is low', 'genre' => 'House')
```

What keys you actually get from this, depends on the ID3 version of each .mp3 file and the actual content (whatever someone wrote into that file).

Comment: So if I only want the Artist, Year, and Album, what version should I use? (I make the .mp3's by hand, so I'll add only those tags.)

Comment: You can leave out the `if(array_key_exists(...)){...}` block if you don't need the genre (won't harm if you keep it). Those 3 basic properties should be implemented in all ID3 versions since ID3v1.

Comment: the function `id3_get_tag` doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: @Stefan The ID3 package is abandoned and no longer included in PHP 7 and up. I added a pointer to a substitute library but since PHP and media metadata are outside my scope of expertise now, I can't say how to use it exactly.